# Resolving Ivy artifacts via Gradle: artifactPattern() vs. layout()

Tags: gradle, ivy

I'm currently looking at resolving Ivy artifacts via Gradle using a custom artifact pattern. Reading through the [IvyArtifactRepository docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html) I'm asking myself what the difference is between using `artifactPattern()` with a custom pattern URL and using `layout()` with `'pattern'` as the *layoutName* and specifying the same custom pattern URL inside the closure. Which one is preferable over the other and why?